# не удаётся выполнить select 2 таблиц из разных БД

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

В базе данных db1 нужно выгрузить таблицу phone, из базы данных db2 нужно выгрузить  таблицу cost. В обеих таблица есть одинаковое значение (столбец) - pourse.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно указать префикс ДБ.
Например так

```
SELECT <...>
FROM db1.phone t1 JOIN db2.cost t2 ON t2.pourse = t1.pourse;
```

Или просто выбор без соединения

```
SELECT pourse
 FROM db1.phone

UNION
SELECT pourse
 FROM db2.cost
```